# Python selenium how to get network tab data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to log the network tab using undetected-chromedriver with `driver.log('performance')` but raises an erorr that `performance` log type was not found.

`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found`

This is my current code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
driver = uc.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get("https://facebook.com")
time.sleep(5)

print(driver.get_log('performance'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ChromeOptions` and set capabilities inside options object instead of `DesiredCapabilities`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://facebook.com")
time.sleep(5)

print(driver.get_log('performance'))
```